# Static introspection of method argument type in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, metaprogramming, introspection

I want to make a templated class which holds an instance of another class and forwards one of its `foo` methods with the correct argument type. Is there a clever meta-programming way of doing a "perfect forwarding" of the inner method?

```
template <typename Inner>
class Outer {
private:
  Inner inner;

public:

  // To-do: replicate foo method of Inner with identical signature,
  // how to pick correct T?
  void foo(T arg) { inner.foo(arg); }

};
```

I can see two classic solutions, but is there a better modern one with meta-programming?

- Inheritance with partially protected interface: `Outer` could publicly inherit from `Inner`. But Inner also has methods which are only to be called by Outer and not the user. Those can be `protected`, ok, but it also tightly couples the implementations of `Outer` and all types of `Inner` classes. The public interface of `Outer` can be arbitrarily extended by public methods in `Inner`, which is not desired.
- Make foo a templated function `template <typename T> void foo(T&& arg) { inner.foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); }`. This is perfect forwarding of the argument, but if a user calls `foo` with the wrong argument, the error reports `Inner::foo` instead of `Outer::foo`. This breaks the encapsulation provided by the public interface of `Outer`.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but it should be possible using something like described here [get type of first, second etc argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879815/c11-get-type-of-first-second-etc-argument-similar-to-result-of)

Comment: True, I guess mine is a duplicate. The answer with `using` is also nice and simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
template <typename Inner>
class Outer : private Inner {
public:
  using Inner::foo;
};
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VIKE50834)

Comment: I think OP's first point is the same as this answer.

Comment: @appleapple The OP was concerned about accidentally exposing methods other than `foo` off `Outer`. This technique doesn't so expose.

Comment: Might want to note that if `foo` is overloaded it will expose all overloads.  I'm not sure if the OP cares about that but someone might.

Comment: Cool, yes, this is an acceptable solution. And pretty straight-forward. I will wait a bit more, but I guess this is going to be the accepted answer, even if it does not use meta-programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way which gives almost perfect error messages:

```
#include <string>

// a type which yields the type we gave it
template<class T> struct passer 
{ 
    using type = T; 
};

// an easy-to-use alias
template<class T> using pass_t = typename passer<T>::type;

// example
template <typename Inner>
class Outer {
private:
  Inner inner;

public:

  // To-do: replicate foo method of Inner with identical signature,
  // how to pick correct T?
  // Ans: with a pass_t
    template<class T>
    auto foo(T&& arg) 
    -> pass_t<decltype(this->inner.foo(std::forward<T>(arg)))>
    {
       return inner.foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); 
    }

};


struct Bar
{
    void foo(std::string const& thing);
};

struct Baz
{
    int foo(int thing) { return thing * 2; };
};

int main()
{

    auto o = Outer<Bar>();
    o.foo(std::string("hi"));
    o.foo("hi");

    int i = 1;

    /* - uncomment for error
    o.foo(i);

    note the nice error message on gcc:
        <source>:41:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'foo'
        <source>:19:10: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int]: reference to type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'int'
    */

// same here:
//    o.foo(1);

// but this is fine
    auto o2 = Outer<Baz>();
    auto x = o2.foo(2);

    // and this is not
    // note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = char const (&)[6]]: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'char const[6]'
//    auto y = o2.foo("dfghj");

}
```

Link here: https://godbolt.org/g/UvsrbP

Comment: This is a very insightful answer, thank you. I prefer the answer with `using Inner::foo`, even though it does not use meta-programming, but it solves the issue I had with public inheritance.

Comment: @olq_plo Oh, I thought you wanted a forwarding solution for encapsulation. Never mind, I'll leave this here in case it's of use to someone.

Comment: It turns out that Boost.CallableTraits can do what I want, more specifically the `args_t` meta-function. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html