# C++ template function from callable class instance to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std-function, stdbind

I do need std::function for stateful operation.

So I would like to make an instance of a class implementing `operator()` into `std::function`. I did test `std::bind` works, but can't wrap it up as a function.

```
struct StatefulOperation
{
    StatefulOperation(int num) : num_(num) {}
    int operator()(int i)
    {
        num_ += i;
        return num_;
    }
    
    int num_;
};


// This works

const StatefulOperation obj(40);
    
using std::placeholders::_1;
std::function<int(int)> op = std::bind(&StatefulOperation::operator(), obj, _1);


// Want something like this

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
std::function<B(A)> op(C& obj);


// This doesn't work

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
std::function<B(A)> op(C& obj)
{
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    return std::bind(&C::operator(), obj, _1);
}
```

The last implementation attempt fails with error like below;

```
main.cpp:52:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:75:35: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘A’
   75 |     std::function<int(int)> f = op(a);
      |                                 ~~^~~
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot deduce `A` and `B` just from the return type. You need to specify them:

```
std::function<int(int)> f = op<int, int>(a);
```

However, you don't really need these additional template parameters. Just use `auto` to deduce the return type:

```
template<typename C>
auto op(C& obj)
{
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    return std::bind(&C::operator(), std::ref(obj), _1);
}
```

The return type will not be exactly the same, but convertible to what you want (`std::function<B(A)>`). If you want to specify the exact return type, you can do so with a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879815/c11-get-type-of-first-second-etc-argument-similar-to-result-of) and [`std::invoke_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that `auto` will also not deduce the right types for the `std::function<B(A)>` but the type returned can be converted to `std::function<int(int)>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using bind you should use [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Also you StatefulOperation should NOT be const (otherwise it can't update its internal state).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct StatefulOperation
{
    StatefulOperation(int num) : num_(num) {}
    int operator()(int i)
    {
        num_ += i;
        return num_;
    }

    int num_;
};

int main()
{
    /*const*/ StatefulOperation obj(40); // your state cannot be const since you are changing its internal state
    
    // instead of bind rely on lambda expressions (bind is still there because of well... history)
    std::function<int(int)> op{ [&](int num) { return obj(num); } };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << op(i) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your class is a callable that implements a function call operator with the expected types, you can initialize a `std::function` in the most simple way:

```
std::function<int(int)> op{StatefulOperation(40)};
```

Do not forget that the state is copied when `op` is copied.